# Python math exp overflow error

Tags: python, integer-overflow

As the title suggests, I get an overflow error when I am using math.exp(). As I am pretty novice and new to programming I would like a little help. I looked for an answer online but I couldn't figure out anything.
Here is the script:

```
Tmin = raw_input("\nEnter temperature value (min): (Press 00 to enter Mean Temperature!)\n")
Tmax = raw_input("\nEnter temperature value (max): (Press 00 to enter Mean Temperature!)\n")
if float(Tmin) > float(Tmax):
    print ("Prepei Tmin < Tmax")
while float(Tmin) > float(Tmax):
        Tmin = raw_input("\nEnter temperature value (min): (Press 00 to enter Mean Temperature!)\n")
        Tmax = raw_input("\nEnter temperature value (max): (Press 00 to enter Mean Temperature!)\n")
if Tmin == ("00") and Tmax == ("00"):
    Tmean = float(raw_input("Enter temperature value (mean): \n"))
else:
    Tmean = ((Tmin)+Tmax)/2)

RHmin = raw_input("\nEnter relative humidity value (min): (Press 00 to enter  Mean Relative Humidity!)\n")
RHmax = raw_input("\nEnter relative humidity value (max): (Press 00 to enter   Mean Relative Humidity!)\n")
if float(RHmin) > float(RHmax):
    print ("Prepei RHmin < RHmax")
while float(RHmin) > float(RHmax):
        RHmin = raw_input("\nEnter relative humidity value (min): (Press 00 to    enter Mean Relative Humidity!)\n")
        RHmax = raw_input("\nEnter relative humidity value (max): (Press 00 to     enter Mean Relative Humidity!)\n")
if RHmin == ("00") and RHmax == ("00"):
    RHmean = float(raw_input("Enter relative humidity value (mean): \n"))
else:
    RHmean = ((float(RHmin)+float(RHmax))/2)

import math
esmax = (0.61051 * (math.exp(17.27 * float(Tmax) + 273.3)))
esmin = (0.61051 * (math.exp(17.27 * float(Tmin) + 273.3)))

print Tmean , RHmean , esmax , esmin
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to use the `math.exp()` function? That function raises _e_ (~= 2.71828) to the power of its argument, so it grows rather quickly. Eg, `math.exp(10)` ~= 22026.465794806718 and `math.exp(100)` ~= 2.6881171418161356e+43, a number with 44 digits before the decimal point.

Comment: My machine would get overflow at 710, therefore anything above it will be a OverflowError.

Comment: Can you give us some meaningful numbers for temperature and skip all that pointless input section? Are you certain you're using the right equation? A reasonable equation shouldn't explode that easily. If I look at [this](http://reliawiki.com/index.php/Temperature-Humidity_Relationship), which may not necessarily be what you're trying to do, the temperature is in the denominator. Also, if `17.27 * float(Tmax) + 273.3` is supposed to be `constant * temperature_in_Kelvin`, you want `17.27 * (float(Tmax) + 273.3)` to get the intended computation order.

Comment: @Reti43 The equation is right. As galaxyan suggests, when the power is greater than 710 I get the overflow error.
You are right about the last one. It's actually:
    17.27 * float(Tmax+273.3)

Comment: That's because a [64bit float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can support up to 1.79e+308 as its max value and `math.log(1.79e308)` is approximately 709.78. Assuming your equation is right, you can't use a temperature higher than 41.09K. And that just doesn't seem right to me. Also, it *is* supposed to be `17.27 * (float(Tmax) + 273.3)` because you want to convert the string `Tmax` to a float. A string plus a float would otherwise give you a TypeError. Another side note, don't mix "prepei" with English. Be consistent.

Comment: @Reti43 Thank you very much for the info. It was really helpful (I did get a TypeError!). Do you know how I can solve the overflow error?

Comment: Like I discussed above, you are limited to an argument no larger than 709.78. If you have to use that formula in vacuum, it can't be helped. But if for example you wanted to calculate `exp(2000) / exp(1000)`, it'd try to calculate `exp(2000)` first in order to divide it with the denominator and that'd be an overflow already. However, using arithmetic tricks we can overcome this with `exp(2000/1000) = exp(2)`. It all depends on what you want to do and for that we'd need more information.

Comment: Why are you sure that your formula is correct? Can you give a citation for it? And as Reti43 said, it would help if you showed us some typical input data, we don't need to see all of that `raw_input` stuff.